# in plotyy the left y axis ticks overlap on right yaxis ticks. how do i delete this overlap? i donot want left y axis ticks seen on right y axis

Tags: matlab, plot

When I use plotyy to make a graph with two y axis. There is a problem that the ticks on primary y axis are also shown on secondary y axis. 
here is the code

```
clear all;
clc;
load ('bval_time.txt');
load ('loadtime.txt');
load ('timeload.txt'); 
load1 =loadtime(:,1);
time1 =timeload(:,1); 
time = bval_time(:,1);
B_value = bval_time(:,2);
[AX,H1,H2]=plotyy(time1,load1,time,B_value,'plot');
title('Load-bvalue-Time variation graph-150grp');
legend('Load','B_value',1);
xlabel('Time(sec)')
set(get(AX(1),'Ylabel'),'String','Load(KN)') 
set(get(AX(2),'Ylabel'),'String','b-value')
set(H1,'LineStyle','-')
set(H2,'LineStyle','-','marker','*')
set(AX(1), 'ylim', [0 15])
set(AX(2), 'ylim', [0 2])
set(AX(1),'YTick',[0:1:15])
set(AX(2),'YTick',[0:0.2:2])
```

Comment: Can you show us some code that reproduces the problem without us needing to have all of your .txt files?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to set `box` property for the left (1st) axes to `off`:

```
set(AX(1),'box','off')
```

Alternatively you can set the same number of ticks on both Y axis. You can do it in two ways:

1) change distance between ticks

```
set(AX(1),'YTick',[0:15])
set(AX(2),'YTick',linspace(0,2,16))
```

2) change axes limit

```
set(AX(1), 'ylim', [0 15])
set(ax(2), 'ylim', [0 3])
set(ax(1),'YTick',0:15)
set(ax(2),'YTick',0:0.2:3)
```

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem. I had redefined the right y-axis ticks, but I wanted to keep the box around the plot.

The solution is to add a new `axes` on top of the ones created by `plotyy` and set the box of this `axes` to "on". However, you have to make sure that this box has the correct x-ticks and that it does not mask the color of the left and right y-axes.

Here is an example plot that shows the problem:

```
x = 1:10;
y = x.^2;
AX = plotyy(x,y,x,y*3)
set(AX(2),'YTick',0:90:400)
```

Notice the extra tick on the right. Solution:

```
set(AX(1),'box','off')
set(AX(2),'box','off')
% create a new axes on top of old ones
new_AX = axes('Position',get(AX(1),'Position'),'XLim',get(AX(1),'XLim'),'YTick',[]);
set(new_AX,'box', 'on')
% reorder things to make y-axes and box visible at the same time
uistack(AX(1),'top')
uistack(AX(2),'top')
set(AX(1),'Color','None')
```

Note: Zooming and panning won't work correctly after creating this extra `axes`. Also, I tested this code with Matlab2011a, but it might not work out of the box with other Matlab versions.